# removing characters from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code which should remove certain characters including white space from a string.

```
parseFloat(value.replace(/\s+/g,"").replace(/,/g, ''))
```

So if i input '1,000,002' or '1 000 002' the output is 1000002, which is correct.

If the input is '1,000,002.00' the output is 1000002, and this is also correct, however if the input is '1 000 002,00' i'm getting back 100000200 which is not correct. Could someone please point me out on how i should modify the regex part please?

Comment: Are you trying to parse numbers with different decimal separators and thousands separators? That's inherently ambiguous: does `5,000` mean 5 or 5000?

Comment: I think it is something hard and error prone to be made through regexp, have you already considered this: http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/ ?

Comment: Can we assume the number of digits in the decimal part is always less than 3?

Comment: yes i'm trying to parse the values with different seperators, since users might have different locale. yes the decimal part is always less than 3. because the values are being returned from the backend using ajax not inputted by the user, so i'm setting the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to support two different locales with the same code, one locale that uses `,` as a thousands separator and another that uses `,` as a decimal point. Ones that use `,` as a decimal point frequently use `.` as a thousands separator, so you'll need to go further.

**If** you can rely on the input having the separators in the right place and **if** you can rely on only having two digits to the right of the decimal, you could do this (long-winded for clarity):

```
// Remove spaces
value = value.replace(/ +/g, '');

// Remove thousands separators (a . or , followed by three digits)
value = value.replace(/[,.](\d{3})/g, '$1');

// Normalize decimal point
value = value.replace(/,/g, '.');

// Parse
value = parseFloat(value);
```

...but those are **awfully big assumptions**. As soon as someone enters `5,001` to mean "five and 1 one-thousandth", you're stuffed; you're going to assume that's 5001.  **Instead**, I would recommend having the user select their input style, and then applying rules specific to that style.

**Live Example**:

```js
// PLEASE NOTE THE REALLY BIG ASSUMPTIONS LISTED IN THE ANSWER
// AND THE SUGGESTION *NOT* TO DO THIS
function parseInput(value) {
  // Remove spaces
  value = value.replace(/ +/g, '');

  // Remove thousands separators
  value = value.replace(/[,.](\d{3})/g, '$1');

  // Normalize decimal point
  value = value.replace(/,/g, '.');

  // Parse
  value = parseFloat(value);
  
  return value;
}

function test(value) {
  snippet.log(value + " => " + parseInput(value));
}

test("1,000,020.10");
test("1.000.020,10");
test("1 000 020.10");
test("1 000 020,10");
test("1000020,10");

test("1,000,020.10");

test("1.000.020,10");
test("1000020,10");

test("1000020,00");
test("1000020,00");
test("1000020");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `parseFloat(string.replace(/,*\s*/g,''));`

The `\s*` removes all spaces and `,*` replaces all `,`